# Determining critical exponent in spontaneous magnetization of 2D Ising model

Tags: statistical-mechanics, ising-model, magnetic-moment, critical-phenomena

I have been solving a problem related to Onsager's relation in Ising model. The initial relation is:

$<s>^8=1-sinh(\frac{2J}{k_BT})^{-4}$

I got that critical temperature is $\frac{2J}{k_BT}=sinh^{-1}(1)\approx0.88$. Then

$<s>^8=1-sinh(\frac{0.88}{1+t})^{-4},$ where $t=\frac{\delta T}{T_C}$ and $T=T_C+\delta T$

From that

$sinh(\frac{0.88}{1+t})^{-4} \approx 1-4.995t-9.01t^2-...$ at t=0

Then follows

$ <s> \sim |\frac{T-T_C}{T_C}|^{1/8}$ $\beta=1/8$

However, somehow this answer should get to

$<s>=B(-t)^{1/8}[1+b(-t)+..]$

Meanwhile I get

$<s>=(-4.995t-9.01t^2-...)^{1/8}=(-4.995t)^{1/8}[1+9/5t+...]^{1/8}$

However, I am not sure where the power of 1/8 dissapears in the series and I would be grateful if someone knows, how to get to that or if I have made a mistake somehwere above. And how is it possible to determine a temperature range valid for this expansion? I get that it should be near to $t=0$, but how to do that exactly?

Edit: the answer states that $B=(8\sqrt2K_C)^{1/8}$ and $b=\frac{1-\frac{9K_C}{\sqrt{2}}}{8}$ where $K_C=\frac{J}{kT_C}$

Answer (score 2):

Let me guess: Yeoman's textbook, right? I had the same problem too, and after long and tedious effort I finally got the answer to this problem!

There are several readings I can give (in total I have 7) but I'll give you the essential ones: *The spontaneous magnetization of a 2D Ising Model* by CN Yang (1951) and *Statistical Mechanics, 3rd Edition* by Paul D. Beale and Pathria R.K. (2011).

But basically, to solve this problem, you need:

#### Step 1

- Define $t=(T-Tc)/Tc$
- Define $Kc=J/(k Tc)$
- Express $\langle s\rangle$ in terms of $t$

Now you have $$\langle s\rangle=\left(1-\sinh\left(\frac{2Kc}{1+t}\right)^{-4}\right)^{1/8}$$

Investigate this near $t=0$

#### Step 2:

Expand $\langle s\rangle$ by Maclaurin series in terms of powers of $t$ (which makes sense if you think about it - "near $t=0$" means "small $t$", hence justifying this expansion!)

#### Step 3:

From the 7 readings (textbooks and papers) I have gathered, by experiments we know $\sinh(2Kc)=1$ (**this is an important result**). Plug this result into the above Maclaurin expansion.

#### Step 4:

Manipulate your expansion into the form of:

$$\langle s\rangle = B(−t)^{1/8}(1+b(−t)+...)$$

---

Note: The Maclaurin series *must be expanded to second order* in $t$ (i.e. you need to expand up to $t^2$). This is tedious - you have to be careful because you need to take the derivative of a messy thing. First derivative of $\sinh^{-4}$ was okay, but the second derivative is where things might get messy!